# .htaccess error on wallpaper website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I installed wallpaper script but it's giving this error on main page:

---

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I think this is .htaccess file. I am pasting the .htaccess file below:

```
#php_flag display_errors On
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteEngine On

#change / with the relative path if you install the script in a subdirectory
#RewriteBase /wallpaperscript.com/script/


#This is for redirecting links with any subdomain to no subdomain
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).wallpapers.net [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wallpapers.net/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

#This is for redirecting links without trailing / to links with trailing /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(.+){3,4}
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-desktop-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $4-desktop-wallpapers$5$6$7
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-desktop-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $3-desktop-wallpapers$4$5$6
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)-desktop-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $2-desktop-wallpapers$3$4$5
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $4-wallpapers$5$6$7
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $3-wallpapers$4$5$6
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $2-wallpapers$3$4$5

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&resource=$1 [L]
```

Is there any problem with this? My site's URL is www.hotwallpapers.pk

Comment: What does it say in your server's error log - check `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Comment: Should this not be on serverfault?

Comment: It's worth asking - do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put: "RewriteBase /" under "RewriteEngine On"  so it looks like this:

## php_flag display_errors On

## Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## change / with the relative path if you install the script in a subdirectory

## RewriteBase /wallpaperscript.com/script/

## This is for redirecting links with any subdomain to no subdomain

## RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).wallpapers.net [NC]

## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wallpapers.net/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

## This is for redirecting links without trailing / to links with trailing /

## RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

## RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).(.+){3,4}

## RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

## RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-desktop-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $4-desktop-wallpapers$5$6$7

## RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-desktop-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $3-desktop-wallpapers$4$5$6

## RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)-desktop-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $2-desktop-wallpapers$3$4$5

## RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $4-wallpapers$5$6$7

## RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $3-wallpapers$4$5$6

## RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)-wallpapers([^/]*)(/){0,1}([^/]*)$ $2-wallpapers$3$4$5

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&resource=$1 [L]